pi 1b ethernet connection cant ping to its actual lan address but can ping its open vpn address
I have a pi at the parents house and have it as an openvpn client of my vpn network.
it stopped doing what it should so when I was around there I rebooted and tried to connect to its ip address via ssh and it wont connect.
ifconfig displays the lan ip address. and that matches what I have in my ssh settings.
when I try and connect via its openvpn address it connects fine.
I can ping from the pi,
I can ping to the pi vpn address but not the lan address.
any ideas why this has stopped being contactable via the lan ip?
I'm hoping that's what's causing my script to not run....
